# updating mysql from table for each row

Tags: php, mysqli

Im stuck and wanted to see if any one could help me out please.
I have built a table in bootstrap v4 which displays products and some data about that product. I currently have a button (green with pencil) that when clicked on in each row sends me to another page where i can see and update all the info on that product and same for red button to delete the product from data base mysqli.
What i am trying to do now is add a save button at the side with the others in blue so that i can alter the price and quantity quickly and save the row like in pic
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHf9p.png)
The first save works and database updates as it supose to but the rest dont. The save button does nothing at all and no matter what i seem to try, i cant get no where.

My code:

```
<?

if(isset($_POST['s1']))
{

                $price = $_POST["price"];
                $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
                $id = $_POST["id"];                 

$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE products set price=?, quantity=? WHERE id = 
?");    
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $price, $quantity, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

header('Location: products.php');
}
?>

  //taken out header of the table       

          <tbody>

            <tr>

<?php
     $raw_results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products") or 
die(mysqli_error($con));
while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){

?>
<form method=post action="">
              <td><input class="form-control size-id" value="<? echo 
$results['id']; ?>" name="id"></td>
              <td><? echo $results['title']; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control size-price" type="text" value=" 
              <? echo $results['quantity']; ?>" name="quantity"></td>                 
              <td><? echo $results['rrp']; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control size-price" type="text" value=" 
              <? echo $results['price']; ?>" name="price"></td>
              <td>
              <button type=submit name=s1 class="btn btn-outline-primary 
btn-sm btn-block-xs-only"> <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</button> 
              <a href="edit_product.php?id=<?=$results['id']?>" class="btn 
btn-outline-success btn-sm" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></a> 
              <a href="delete_product.php?id=<?=$results['id']?>" class="btn 
btn-outline-danger btn-sm" role="button"><i class="fa fa-times" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></a>
              </td>
 </tr>
             <?
  }
?>
          </tbody>
```

Comment: Your html markup is __invalid__. You cannot wrap `<td>` in `<form>`.

Comment: you are going to want to use AJAX for this

Comment: thank you mulder. what would you suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to wan't to use AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) for this

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

This way you can update your quantity and price without having the need to refresh the entire page. Also there is no need for a form tag with table cells in them which is invalid.

Please read through this tutorial and you will have an idea what to do. If not i could even provide you with a small code example.

The following script will alert the row_id and quantity you send to the server, without the need of a form.

Not that in my example i put the row_id by hand, of course your PHP script would take care of such things

Example (assumes index.html and echo.php are in same folder):

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><input id="quantity_1" type="text" size="3" name="quantity_1" /></td>
    <td><img src="save.png" onclick="save(1);" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><input id="quantity_2" type="text" size="3" name="quantity_2" /></td>
    <td><img src="save.png" onclick="save(2);" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function save(row_id) {
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_' + row_id).value;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "echo.php?row_id=" + row_id + "&quantity=" + quantity, true);
    xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**echo.php**

```
<?php

echo 'row id: ' . intval($_GET['row_id']);
echo ' quantity: ' . intval($_GET['quantity']);
```

Well echo.php could be your script that saves the submitted values ;) But i leave that part upto you. Be sure to validate input. Never put $_GET vars straight in a SQL query.

Comment: would you be able to give me a sample please. Been reading but never done ajax

Comment: sure just give me 15 minutes or so

Comment: so i added the example i hope it makes sense to you

Comment: no problem, if you wan't select mark my answer for solving the question please

Comment: Managed to get this all sorted thanks to you. The table now updates straight away and displays alert with "product quantity + price updated"